# Rename tag [hms] to [huawei-mobile-services]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

Please rename the tag [hms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hms) to [huawei-mobile-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei-mobile-services) on Stack Overflow.

HMS stands for `Huawei Mobile Services` and people who are creating questions usually try to search for tag starting with `huawei-`.

A tag named simply [hms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hms) might be not clear for beginners.

I based my suggestion on Google's tags. There is [google-mobile-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-mobile-services), but not [gms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good suggestion; done and done.

The [hms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hms) tag still exists as a synonym of [huawei-mobile-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei-mobile-services), in order to avoid breaking anyone's bookmarks. But all attempts to tag a question [hms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hms) will replace that tag with [huawei-mobile-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei-mobile-services), which will hopefully prevent any confusion and avoid any mistagging.

(If it is later determined that the acronym "HMS" is ambiguous—i.e., that there are other programming-related concepts using the same acronym—then we can remove the synonym at that time.)

Before doing this, I also verified that all questions with the [hms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hms) tag *were* actually about Huawei Mobile Services. There were only 14 of them that didn't mention "huawei" directly in the body of the question, and all of those were indeed about Huawei-related stuff. Although most of them were terribly unclear, so that was handled, too...

Comment: Thank you for your efforts.